# CSS change hyperlinks colour on hover of a DIV

Tags: html, css, hover, division

I have a problem with getting hyperlinks to change color properties with the DIV on hover.

I want a white div with the links being #80c8ac. The on hover the div becomes #80c8ac and the links #fff. The text is to remain #152128.

My issue that I can't overcome is that the text changes to #fff on the hover state and the links become #fff in the first state

here's the HTML

```css
.job.hot {
  color: #152128;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 20px;
}
#ja-jobs-widget a {
  color: #80c8ac;
}
#ja-jobs-widget summary {
  color: #80c8ac;
}
.job.hot:hover {
  background-color: #00D9BD;
}
.job.hot:hover,
#ja-jobs-widget {
  color: #152128;
}
.job.hot:hover,
#ja-jobs-widget a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ja-job-list-container">
  <div class="ja-job-list">
    <div class="job hot">
      <h2 class="title"><a data-job-id="507911" href="#" title="Front End Developer">Front End Developer</a></h2> 
      <div class="meta">
        <ul class="classifications">
          <li data-id="16813">IT &amp; Telecomms</li>
          <li data-id="16814">Web / Multimedia Developer</li>
          <li data-id="16815">Sydney</li>
          <li data-id="16816">Permanent / Full Time</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="date-posted">12/6/2016</p>
      </div>
      <p class="summary">This is an outstanding opportunity for a Front End Developer to join this highly skilled team.</p>
      <a class="view-details" data-job-id="507911" href="#" title="More..">More..</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

The issue described above is caused by the

```
.job.hot:hover, #ja-jobs-widget a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

I've tried lots of combinations including trying to directly specify classes like 'title' & 'view-details'

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/vm02095v/20/

Comment: There is no id  `ja-jobs-widget` in your elements.... So which element are you targeinmg wit that id

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming I've understood you, in your code the links do not go white on `:hover`, what you have tried makes them go permantly white. Correct?

In your code you posted above, the id `#ja-jobs-widget` is nowhere in your code. The CSS should be as below to target the `a` tags:

```
.job.hot:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Here we say that on `:hover` of `.job.hot` find any `a` tags inside it, and make them white.

See snippet below for result.

```css
.job.hot {
  color: #152128;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 20px;
}
#ja-jobs-widget a {
  color: #80c8ac;
}
#ja-jobs-widget summary {
  color: #80c8ac;
}
.job.hot:hover {
  background-color: #00D9BD;
}
.job.hot:hover,
#ja-jobs-widget {
  color: #152128;
}
.job.hot:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ja-job-list-container">
  <div class="ja-job-list">
    <div class="job hot">
      <h2 class="title"><a data-job-id="507911" href="#" title="Front End Developer">Front End Developer</a></h2> 
      <div class="meta">
        <ul class="classifications">
          <li data-id="16813">IT &amp; Telecomms</li>
          <li data-id="16814">Web / Multimedia Developer</li>
          <li data-id="16815">Sydney</li>
          <li data-id="16816">Permanent / Full Time</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="date-posted">12/6/2016</p>
      </div>
      <p class="summary">This is an outstanding opportunity for a Front End Developer to join this highly skilled team.</p>
      <a class="view-details" data-job-id="507911" href="#" title="More..">More..</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

If `#ja-jobs-widget` is the id of the container of this code, and you want to make sure that only links inside the container with that id go white, you could do this:

```
#ja-jobs-widget .job.hot:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

So first find `#ja-jobs-widget`, then on `:hover` of `.job.hot`, make all `a` tags inside go white.

Answer (score 0):

Change css like this...

```
.job.hot:hover a, #ja-jobs-widget a {
 color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the text only with your css line `.job.hot:hover, #ja-jobs-widget a { color: #fff; }`
Instead, you want to target the links only. So instead use `.job.hot:hover a { color:fff; }`

Full code demo in the folowing fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/53g6n56q/

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any element with id `ja-jobs-widget` so i have modified the CSS based on class `.job.hot`.

**Try the below snippet:**

```css
.job.hot {
  color: #152128;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 20px;
}
.job.hot a {
  color: #80c8ac;
}
.job.hot:hover {
  background-color: #00D9BD;
}
.job.hot:hover a,
.job.hot:hover a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ja-job-list-container">
  <div class="ja-job-list">
    <div class="job hot">
      <h2 class="title"><a data-job-id="507911" href="#" title="Front End Developer">Front End Developer</a></h2> 
      <div class="meta">
        <ul class="classifications">
          <li data-id="16813">IT &amp; Telecomms</li>
          <li data-id="16814">Web / Multimedia Developer</li>
          <li data-id="16815">Sydney</li>
          <li data-id="16816">Permanent / Full Time</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="date-posted">12/6/2016</p>
      </div>
      <p class="summary">This is an outstanding opportunity for a Front End Developer to join this highly skilled team.</p>
      <a class="view-details" data-job-id="507911" href="#" title="More..">More..</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be done as follows:

```css
 .job.hot {
     color:#152128;
     background-color: #fff;
     padding: 20px;
     width: 30%;
     float: left;
     margin: 0 15px 0 20px;
    }

    .job.hot a {
  color: #80c8ac;
}
.job.hot:hover {
  background-color: #00D9BD;
}
.job.hot:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ja-job-list-container">
      <div class="ja-job-list">
        <div class="job hot">
            <h2 class="title"><a data-job-id="507911" href="#" title="Front End Developer">Front End Developer</a></h2> 
            <div class="meta">
                <ul class="classifications"> 
                    <li data-id="16813"> IT &amp; Telecomms </li> 
                    <li data-id="16814"> Web / Multimedia Developer </li> 
                    <li data-id="16815"> Sydney </li> 
                    <li data-id="16816"> Permanent / Full Time </li> 
                </ul> 
                <p class="date-posted"> 12/6/2016 </p> 
            </div> 
                <p class="summary">This is an outstanding opportunity for a Front End Developer to join this highly skilled team.</p> 
            <a class="view-details" data-job-id="507911" href="#" title="More..">More..</a> 
     </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```